# How can I render <Card.Text> as <div> element and not as <p>?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

For `<Card.Body>` there seems to be a *parameter* named `as` which is of type `elementType` and defaults to `<div>`.

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/#card-body-props

Now `<Card.Text>` defaults to `<p>` which results in warnings on my website as I have nested `<div>` elements inside `<Card.Text>`

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a descendant of `<p>`

So basically two questions:

1. How can I change/set the elementtype on `Card.Body`? The following attempts did not get reflected in the produced html (checked with Chrome DevTools): `<Card.Body as="p">...</Card.Body>` nor did this `<Card.Body as="<p>">...</Card.Body>`
2. How can I change the elementtype on `<Card.Text>`?

---

This is what my component looks like

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card"
import Tags from "./tags"
import TimeToRead from "./time-to-read"

const Post = ({ title, slug, date, body, fluid, tags, timeToRead }) => {
  return (
    <Card className="mb-3 shadow-lg" bg="concrete" id="hoverable">
      <Link to={slug}>
        <Img
          className="card-image-top"
          style={{ maxHeight: "150px" }}
          fluid={fluid}
        ></Img>
        <Card.ImgOverlay
          style={{
            pointerEvents: "none",
          }}
        >
          <Tags tags={tags} />
        </Card.ImgOverlay>
      </Link>

      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>{title}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Subtitle>
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <span className="text-info">{date}</span>
            <TimeToRead minutes={timeToRead} />
          </div>
        </Card.Subtitle>
        <hr />
        <Card.Text as="div">{body}</Card.Text>
        <Link
          to={slug}
          className="btn btn-outline-primary float-right text-uppercase"
        >
          Read more
        </Link>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default Post
```

Comment: how do you mean by doesn't work when you try `<Card.Body as="p"></Card.Body>`. In the URL that you provide, you can edit the example and I can use `as="p"` there.

Comment: And `<Card.Text as="span"></Card.Text>` works as well

Comment: Thx for replying. By "it doesn't work" I mean it doesn't get reflected in the produced html. Checked with Chrome Developertools

Comment: can you show us how you render the card component?

Comment: I will try my best and update my question. But be aware I am a novice to react...

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, essentially. I used an unordered list inside the text for the `<Card.Body>` and the console displayed the following warning:

```
validateDOMNesting(...): <ul> cannot appear as descendent of <p>.
```

Wrapping the list content inside a `<div>` just added to the warning list. As suggested above, I amended the `<Card.Text>` tag, but as follows:

```
 <Card.Text as="div">
```

The warning disappeared and the text renders. Note, you have to adjust the styling, depending on how the styling cascade is configured.